# Alias in mysql select query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, alias

I am a MSSQL user now I am converting my database to MySQL,
I am writing following query in MySQL.

```
select col1 as [My Column] from table1
```

> Error : You have an error in sql syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a syntax error because the escape character (*delimiter*) is different from `MSSQL`. You need to use `backtick` instead of brackets. eg,

```
select col1 as `My Column` from table1
```

MySQL => backtick 
MSSQL => bracket

Answer (score 1):

Remove `[]`

```
select col1 as MyAliasName from table1
```

Or

```
select col1 as `My Alias Name` from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

Aliasses work the same in mysql, but you need to use other delimiters:
Instead of:

```
select col1 as [My Column] from table1;
```

use

```
select col1 as ´My Column´ from table1;
```

or without any delimiters if the table/column-name doesn't contain any special characters:

select col1 as MyColumn from table1;

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1 as my_column from tablename;
```