# Can I alias a select query in a multiline update in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, variables, alias, multiple-select-query

I'm trying to make this MySQL code more readable:

```
UPDATE customers
    SET last_order_date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM orders WHERE customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id),
        added_note = (SELECT note FROM orders WHERE customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id 
                     AND date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM orders WHERE customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id));
```

The example code adds the date and note of the most recent order of each customer to the corresponding row in the customer table, but it has to `SELECT` the most recent order date for any given customer twice.

I tried the alias syntax suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806567/alias-in-mysql-select-query):

```
UPDATE customers
    SET last_order_date = (SELECT MAX(date) AS `maxdate` FROM orders WHERE customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id),
        added_note = (SELECT note FROM orders WHERE customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id 
                     AND date = `maxdate`);
```

I also tried without the `AS` keyword:

```
UPDATE customers
    SET last_order_date = (SELECT MAX(date) maxdate FROM orders WHERE customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id),
        added_note = (SELECT note FROM orders WHERE customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id 
                     AND date = maxdate);
```

But in neither cases the alias is recognized.

Is there a way I can assign an intermediate result to a name and refer to it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MySQL 8.0, you can use a CTE:

```
WITH o AS (
  SELECT date, note, customer_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY date DESC) AS rownum 
  FROM orders 
)
UPDATE customers AS c 
INNER JOIN o USING (customer_id)
SET c.last_order_date = o.date,
    c.added_note = o.note
WHERE o.rownum = 1;
```

With older versions of MySQL that don't support CTE, here's how I would code it:

```
UPDATE customers AS c
INNER JOIN orders AS o1 
  ON c.customer_id=o1.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders AS o2 
  ON o1.customer_id=o2.customer_id AND o1.date < o2.date
SET c.last_order_date = o1.date,
    c.added_note = o1.note
WHERE o2.customer_id IS NULL;
```

The outer join returns NULL for all columns of the joined table when there is no match. If there's no row `o2` with a greater date than row `o1`, then `o1` must be the row with the greatest date for the respective customer_id.

The latter solution may result in ties. That is, there may be more than one row tied for the greatest date for a given customer. The CTE solution won't have that issue.

Comment: Note I have not tested this. I encourage you to test it with a small sample of data before you try it on your real data. Make sure it behaves the way you want and that you understand how it works.